# Use Bluetooth dongle with Blutooth-enabled laptop

Tags: audio, bluetooth, headphones, latency, protocol

I have a Lenovo Yoga 2 ultrabook running Windows 10 that comes with Bluetooth support but lacks aptX support. I have Sony MDR10RBT headphones that support aptX.

The audio latency I experience while gaming using these headphones is unacceptable, and I expect that this is due to the lack of aptX support on my machine.

If I purchased a Bluetooth USB dongle that supports aptX, would this resolve the issue? Would I have to uninstall existing drivers on my computer? Which product do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would work.  If you plug a USB Bluetooth dongle into a laptop that has built-in Bluetooth it would just show up as another adapter.  You can disable the built-in adapter by going to Network and Sharing Center > Change Adapter Settings.  This will force the system to use the USB dongle.